non blocking udp socket recvfrom does not recieve
I have an assignment that asks me to set up a UDP server that accepts non blocking requests from multiple users without the use of select or fork.
Ok, neat challenge. My idea: let's create a non blocking UDP socket and periodically recvfrom, since that is precisely what the assigment is asking (the server periodically checks if there's a registration request [...]).
Issue: everytime I recvfrom I always get EWOULDBLOCK even if the client is sending messages. I wrote a minimal working example if you are interested in that:
// server.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024
#define PORT 12345

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char buffer[BUFSIZE];
    int rv;
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    socklen_t addr_len = sizeof(addr);


    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0);

    bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, addr_len);

    while (1)
    {
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        rv = recvfrom(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &addr_len);
        if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK)
        {
            puts(".");
        }
        else
        {
            char ipstr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &addr, ipstr, addr_len);
            buffer[rv] = '\0';
            printf("new request from [%s:%d]:\n%s\n", ipstr, htons(addr.sin_port), buffer);
        }
      
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}


// client.c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024
#define PORT 12345
#define IPADDR "127.0.0.1"

const char* msgtosend = "can you hear me?";

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char buffer[BUFSIZE];
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, IPADDR, &addr.sin_addr.s_addr);

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));

    while (1)
    {
        send(sock, msgtosend, strlen(msgtosend), 0);
        puts(".");
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}

This example works perfectly fine if we make the socket blocking btw.
My guess is that there's something about non blocking sockets I don't understand and searching about it hasn't lead me anywhere yet. I'm hoping you could help me out!

One obvious thing: you should only consider recvfrom failed if rv<0 instead of blindly checking errno w/o checking rv. And if course you check that bind has actually succeeded.

@SteffenUllrich I hope you can forgive all the bad practices and missed error checking, it's just a minimal example as I said

Checking the return from recvfrom is not just error checking. It is the precondition for  even looking at errno.

@SteffenUllrich oh... so errno is not reset if the recvfrom has worked, I see, thank you

@ugo_capeto The prime directive: a func doesn't set/touch errno unless it detects an error. This is for speed/simplicity. If you call foo, foo calls bar which returns -1 and sets errno, then foo calls baz as an alternative, which does not error, foo returns 0 (no error) but errno remains set. True for 99.44% of funcs. But, some funcs can't return -1 (or null or whatever) for error, such as math functions. The rule there is caller clears errno (because of the directive), calls the function, and checks errno. This is the old way for math funcs. See: man math_error

As a side note, the preferred pattern to create a forever loop is to use for(;;) { ... }. Also, while(true) would be more C++ than while(1).

The receiving loop would work a lot better if you have it block inside select() until the socket is ready-for-read, instead of having it block inside sleep(1).  (and by "better" I mean your program would react to incoming UDP packets more-or-less instantaneously rather than needlessly delaying for up to 1 second before handling them)

@JeremyFriesner: the stated requirements prohibit select -- although they don't prohibit poll which would do the same thing, suggesting this course was designed during the Reagan presidency and never updated. (It also doesn't appear to be teaching the IPv6 API.)

@dave_thompson_085 ah, you are right.  That's a weird requirement, something akin to "design an automobile but you aren't allowed to use any wheels"  :)

as @SteffenUllrich pointed out, before checking errno we must make sure that recvfrom has a bad return value.
int rv = recvfrom(..);
if (rv < 0 && errno == EWOULDBLOCK) { ... }

silly mistake, my bad.

I would expect the if() body, rather than being puts(".");, to also clear errno for the subsequent errors -- OR -- perform errno = 0; before the recvfrom() call.

The fix to ensure you check the return value from the recvfrom() before using errno is all that is necessary to get this working at a basic level.
However, your usage of inet_pton() and inet_ntop() have a bit of code smell about them. For IPv4, both should be using the address of a struct in_addr in the appropriate places. See man7.org. Doesn't matter so much for client.c in this case, but when I ran your server.c code it didn't emit the inbound client addresses correctly until this was corrected.
